# double deletion in QStackedWidget in a QtContainer

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QStackedWidget in my Form and I am adding certain widgets dynamically.

```
    m_lineEdit = new QLineEdit();
    m_label = new QLabel();
    m_lineEdit->setText(name());
    m_label->setText(name());
    innerUi->stackedWidget->addWidget(m_lineEdit);
    innerUi->stackedWidget->addWidget(m_label);
    connect(m_lineEdit, &QLineEdit::editingFinished, [this]() {
        m_label->setText(m_lineEdit->text());
        innerUi->stackedWidget->setCurrentWidget(m_label);
    });
    innerUi->stackedWidget->setCurrentWidget(m_label);
```

This works well, when I use it. But it crashes when I close the application.

I tried to investigate the issue and observed the followings. The parent of stackedwidget is stored in a QVector. Sometimes I dynamically remove elements from QVector.

```
m_tasks.removeOne(task); 
mainUi->tasksLayout->removeWidget(task);
task->setParent(nullptr); 
mainUi->statusLabel->setText(getCompleteStatus());
delete task;
```

So, this causes double deletion. Can someone suggest me how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [QObject::deleteLater](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) instead of `delete`. You are correctly setting parent to null which means that your object should not be deleted by default Qt mechanism but it still might be invoked by signal/slot connection that wasn't removed.